# How to deploy on JBoss AS 7 from Eclipse Juno?

Tags: eclipse, jboss, jboss7.x, eclipse-juno

I'm using Eclipse Juno and want to test my Java web app in JBoss AS 7. How do I configure Eclipse so that it starts JBoss AS 7 and deploys the war? Also remote debugging should work. It seems I can't use JBoss Tools as they are only released for the previous Eclipse versions (Indigo and Helios).

Any pointers?

Comment: In the meantime, JBoss Tools 3.3, which might be a bit more compatible with Juno: https://community.jboss.org/en/tools/blog/2012/08/22/summer-time-with-new-release-soa-tools-and-a-bit-of-juno-and-fedora-news

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that the current stable releases of JBoss Tools supports Eclipse Indigo (3.7.2) and Helios (3.6.x) as detailed **[here](https://www.jboss.org/tools/download/stable.html)** :

> [image]

### Is there a Beta Update site for Juno ?

**[This](https://www.jboss.org/tools/download/installation/update_3_4)** page has the details of the update site for Juno :

> Instructions will be posted after the first Juno-compatible milestone
>   is available.
>
> Until then, just point your Eclipse 4.2 (Juno) installation at this
>   site to install the latest nightly build. Note that there is no
>   guarantee of quality with a nightly, nor do we guarantee it won't set
>   your computer on fire.

Update site : [JBoss Tools - Core - Nightly Build Update Site](http://download.jboss.org/jbosstools/updates/nightly/core/trunk/)

It bears repeating, that the above is unstable at the moment.

### Stability of JBoss Tools Beta for Juno ?

From **[this](https://community.jboss.org/community/tools/blog/2012/06/21/jboss-tools-33-and-developer-studio-50-final-release)** page:

> Since the first version of Eclipse Juno is arriving soon it is worth
>   mentioning that JBoss Tools from its updatesite can be installed on
>   top of Juno.
>
> It is though not guaranteed everything works, we know that especially
>   Hibernate Dali/JPT integration have issues since here the API has
>   changed greatly.
>
> But if you are a Juno early-adopter then do please try run JBoss Tools
>   on it and if you find issues let us know in the forum or on JIRA.

Also, **[this](https://community.jboss.org/message/740981#740981)** might be of interest :

> Our latest Beta, soon coming CR1 runs on Eclipse Juno  (3.8/4.2) *except* for the Eclipse Dali/JPA integration

Answer (score 0):

I use Eclipse Juno and I installed Jboss Tool for helios version.

Works like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

This stable version of JBoss Tools 4.0.0 works well with Eclipse 4.2 (Juno).

Steps :

- Add this URL '[JBoss Tools - Core - Stable Release Update Site](http://download.jboss.org/jbosstools/updates/stable/juno/) ' to  site URL's 
  (`Help > Install New Software > Add` )
- Select the features to install, or click the Select All button.
- Click Next, agree to the license terms, and install.

Note : You can also download JBoss Tools as individual zips for offline installation.

Refer :[JBoss Tools 4.0.1.Final Stable Release](https://www.jboss.org/tools/download/stable/4_0)

Answer (score 0):

Please find the below steps to add ***JBoss Tools*** for ***Eclipse Juno***

1. Go to Help -> Eclipse Marketplace
2. Type JBoss Tools in the Find text box
3. You can see the JBoss Tools (Juno) icon in the listed items with install button
4. Click on the install button
5. Restart your Eclipse to reflect.

Comment: It reflect but while configuring for jboss 7.2 it gives error for a jar named "twiddle", how to resolve that?